# Unable to "npm install" on project

Tags: python, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to npm install on an existing project with a new computer but I got an error "gyp ERR!".

I tried to reinstall NPM, reinstall python with an older version, install NPM with different version but it doesn't work and the error is the same. I have never got this error before.

I tried to remove node-modules and download Visual Build Tools with the same result.

Here is the error log :

```
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path D:\APCOM\wamp64\www\dev\newPlanSub\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/node-v16.13.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/node-v16.13.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! (node:12632) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Apcom\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\fibers\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Apcom\\.node-gyp\\16.13.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Apcom\\.node-gyp\\16.13.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Apcom\\.node-gyp\\16.13.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\fibers',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\fibers\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\APCOM\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\newPlanSub\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\APCOM\wamp64\www\dev\newPlanSub\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Apcom\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-27T11_10_12_874Z-debug.log[1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXDoa.png
```

EDIT :
Tried to reset windows on the affected computer. Gyp Error message again.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\wamp64\www\plansubs\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp64\\www\\plansubs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp64\www\plansubs\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\capit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-27T13_17_56_362Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I use :

Windows 10 Family
Version 21H1
Build : 19043.1320

Comment: `node-gyp` requires some things to be installed on your machine in order to be able to run. Follow their guidelines, this usually resolves the issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. This was not because of my node.js configuration nor a python issue. The issue was in my project.

I did an npm run watch on the latest commit and this one was bugged.

I just took the precedent commit with npm run prod and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Check if you have a virtual environment, if not (python -m venv “location of project”)
Step 2 - Select interpreter since virtual environment is created(in Visual Studio code its ctrl+shift+p ) then click "select interpreter", then select "enter interpreter path", then select "browse your file system to find a python interpreter", then goto the installed virtual environment the select the python.exe file
Step 3 - open terminal in VS code, then in file path goto script folder(cd Scripts) then enter ".\activate"
Step 4 - pip install npm

Hopefully this works for you